# Insert new columns based on the union of colnames of two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to write a R function to insert many 0 vectors into a existed data.frame. Here is the example:

```
Data.frame 1
    A   B   C   D
1   1   3   4   5
2   4   5   6   7
3   4   5   6   2
4   4   55  2   3

Data.frame 2
    A   B   E   X
11  5   1   5   5
22  44  55  9   6
33  12  4   2   4
44  9   7   4   2
```

Based on the union of two colnames (that is A,B,C,D,E, X), I want to update the two data frames like:

```
Data.frame 1 (new)

    A   B   C   D   E   X
1   1   3   4   5   0   0
2   4   5   6   7   0   0
3   4   5   6   2   0   0
4   4   55  2   3   0   0

Data.frame 2 (new)

    A   B   C   D   E   X
11  5   1   0   0   5   5
22  44  55  0   0   9   6
33  12  4   0   0   2   4
44  9   7   0   0   4   2
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 (Thanks @Jilber for the edits)

I'm assuming the order of columns don't matter -

```
df2part <- subset(df2,select = setdiff(colnames(df2),colnames(df1)))*0
df1f <- cbind(df1,df2part)
df1part <- subset(df1,select = setdiff(colnames(df1),colnames(df2)))*0
df2f <- cbind(df2,df1part)
```

If the order really matters, then just reorder the columns

```
df2f <- df2f[, sort(names(df2f))]
```

Output

```
> df1f
  A  B C D E X
1 1  3 4 5 0 0
2 4  5 6 7 0 0
3 4  5 6 2 0 0
4 4 55 2 3 0 0
> df2f
    A  B C D E X
11  5  1 0 0 5 5
22 44 55 0 0 9 6
33 12  4 0 0 2 4
44  9  7 0 0 4 2
```

Option 2 -

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(df1)
df2 <- data.table(df2)

df1names <- colnames(df1)
df2names <- colnames(df2)
df1[,setdiff(df2names,df1names) := 0]
df2[,setdiff(df1names,df2names) := 0]
```

Comment: The OP apparently wants the added columns to be filled with 0's.

Comment: Ah, phooey. I should not be trying to answer at this hour. Let me fix it, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It works well. One more question, if the row.numbers are different for two data.frames, is there any easy way to set the row.number for df1part and df2part? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at `rownames`.